Does any sampradaya used any term to Criticize madhwas and madhwacharya?
Does any sampradaya used any term to madhwas and madhwacharya to criticize them like Vaishnavas call advaitis as mayavadi , prachanna bauddha

Madhva was widely criticized for citing sources that cannot be traced.  But i don't know if he was name-called for doing that @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud

His doctrines were also criticized for being influenced by Islam and Christianity. @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud

@SK there is little to no evidence he actually based any of his doctrines on Islam and Christianity, in authentic sources about his life.
